# Allow Camera and Microphone Access Without User Input

Tags: powershell, xamarin.forms, uwp

Have a UWP application that requires Camera and Microphone access.

This application will be deployed on 1,000+ computers through SCCM.

We don't want to have someone touch all 1,000+ computers to allow these in privacy settings.

Is there a way to script or automate that these be allowed default for the UWP?

Comment: What's the application?

Comment: Normally security settings on multiple computers would be managed via [Security Policy Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/administer-security-policy-settings). Have you looked there, to see if there are any UWP-related settings? I recommend asking at https://superuser.com/. Then in the app itself, be sure to add those permissions to the app manifest. And just in case user does turn it off, have app check for exception that permission is denied, give user option to open the windows setting page where they can turn it back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Allow Camera and Microphone Access Without User Input

I'm afraid there is no such api that could skip user confirm, as you know there are many capabilities need to be confirmed for security reason. and it's by design and managed by system. And the confirm dialog will appear only when you need to use the related APIs(camera capture). Once permission is granted once that permission will persist until the user retracts it.

If you do want this feature please go ahead post this with windows feedback hub app.

Comment: Thanks, ended up switching over to WPF.